# weird networkonmainthread exception: only on galaxy nexus and not in the emulator

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, networking

In my Android app I use a thread to download an image from the internet, but for some reason when I run the app on my galaxy nexus a networkonmainthread exception is thrown but not if I run the app in the emulator (tested Android Versions 2.3.3 and 4.0.3).

```
Thread ImageLoaderThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

 bitmap= DrawableManager.fetchDrawable(URL);

 });
```

Because the GUI starts slowly when I start the thread directly on start-up I get the impression, that the thread indeed runs on the GUI thread...but why???

Comment: It shouldn't matter how long it takes to load something; your thread will start where you set it to start (it cant just jump from one parent thread to another). It is working 100% on the emulator or is it just not crashing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes it completely works on the emulator and the downloaded image gets displayed. Start-up with the thread takes a couple of seconds longer than without it so I'm pretty sure that the GUI thread is involved in the downloading.

Comment: You can always make the new thread wait. It sounds like the download happens before the UI thread is ready, crashing the app. Try starting the thread after the UI thread becomes available.

Comment: Even if I do so and for example start the thread only after a button has been pressed, it still throws a networkonmainthread exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you build.  You are building using [Honeycomb SDK](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-20035295-251.html) (for Android 3.0 and higher) when building for the device.  `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is never thrown with older SDKs.

You are not using the same SDK for the emulator, at least not when building to test on 2.3.3.  If you use the same build configuration when testing on 2.3.3 and 4.0.3, that would completely explain all the results you are seeing.

Accessing the network on the main thread was never considered good practice (the concern is UI responsiveness as no other thread can serve the UI while you are waiting for network to respond), but it was not strictly banned in the API until Honeycomb.

Read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) to move your network access into an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Ok thanks I use AsyncTask now but I still wonder why the thread I created threw the exception. I think the whole point of creating a thread is that it does not run on the GUI Thread.

Comment: @user1406731 - But you need to start your thread, which means literally invoking its `start` method.  If you invoke just the `run` method directly from the main thread, then the code within it still runs on the calling thread (no new thread is started); never invoke `run` directly.